# copy & swap in base and derived class

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, derived-class, base-class

I recently read about [copy & swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) and am now trying to implement the ctors in a base and derived class. I have the four constructors in both my base and derived class, however I am unsure how to implement the assignment operator of the derived class.

```
explicit Base(int i) : m_i{i} {}
Base(const Base & other) : m_i{other.m_i}
Base(Base && other) : Base(0) { swap(*this, other); }
Base & operator=(Base other) { swap(*this, other); return *this; }
friend void swap(Base & a, Base & b) noexcept {
    using std::swap;
    swap(a.m_i, b.m_i);
}

explicit Derived(int j) : Base(42), m_j(j) {}
Derived(const Derived & other) : Derived(other.m_j) {}
Derived(Derived && other) : Derived(other.m_j) { swap(*this, other); }
Derived & operator=(Derived other) { /*???*/ }
friend void swap(Derived & a, Derived & b) noexcept {
    using std::swap;
    swap(a.m_j, b.m_j);
}
```

Comment: Rule-of-thump: Single-argument non-copy/move ctors should be `explicit`: You really don't want to have an implicit conversion from `int` to `Base`...

Comment: Also, you need to define `swap` in `Derived` as well, unless the one for `Base` is good enough

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider using `= default` as much as possible.  And if we are talking about public inheritance, you really need a virtual destructor as well.

Here is how your `Base` would look using the copy/swap style:

```
class Base
{
    int m_i;
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    Base(const Base& other) = default;
    Base& operator=(Base other) noexcept
    {
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }
    Base(Base&& other) noexcept
        : Base(0)
    {
        swap(*this, other);
    }

    explicit Base(int i) noexcept
        : m_i{i}
        {}

    friend void swap(Base& a, Base& b) noexcept
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(a.m_i, b.m_i);
    }
};
```

The only difference from what you have is that I've added the virtual destructor, and used `= default` for the copy constructor.

Now for `Derived`:

```
class Derived
    : public Base
{
    int m_j;
public:
    Derived(const Derived& other) = default;
    Derived& operator=(Derived other) noexcept
    {
        swap(*this, other);
        return *this;
    }
    Derived(Derived&& other) noexcept
        : Derived(0)
    {
        swap(*this, other);
    }

    explicit Derived(int j) noexcept
        : Base(42)
        , m_j{j}
        {}

    friend void swap(Derived& a, Derived& b) noexcept
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(static_cast<Base&>(a), static_cast<Base&>(b));
        swap(a.m_j, b.m_j);
    }
};
```

I've let the compiler implicitly take care of the destructor since the compiler will implicitly give me a virtual one that does the right thing in this case.

Again I've explicitly defaulted the copy constructor.  This corrects a bug in your version which neglects to copy `Base`.

The `operator=` looks just like the `Base` version.

The `Derived` move constructor does not need to move or copy anything from `other` since it is going to `swap` with `other`.

The `Derived` `swap` function must swap the `Base` part as well as the `Derived` part.

---

Now consider **not** using the copy/swap idiom.  This can be surprisingly easier, and in some cases, higher performing.

For `Base` you can use `= default` for all 5 of your special members:

```
class Base
{
    int m_i;
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    Base(const Base&) = default;
    Base& operator=(const Base&) = default;
    Base(Base&&) = default;
    Base& operator=(Base&&) = default;

    explicit Base(int i) noexcept
        : m_i{i}
        {}

    friend void swap(Base& a, Base& b) noexcept
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(a.m_i, b.m_i);
    }
};
```

The only work that is really required here is your custom constructor and `swap` function.

`Derived` is even easier:

```
class Derived
    : public Base
{
    int m_j;
public:
    explicit Derived(int j) noexcept
        : Base(42)
        , m_j{j}
        {}

    friend void swap(Derived& a, Derived& b) noexcept
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(static_cast<Base&>(a), static_cast<Base&>(b));
        swap(a.m_j, b.m_j);
    }
};
```

**All** 5 of the special members can be implicitly defaulted!

We couldn't default them in the `Base` because we needed to specify the virtual destructor, which inhibits the generation of the move members, and the generation of the copy members is deprecated with a user-declared destructor.  But since we do not need to declare the destructor in `Derived`, we can just let the compiler handle everything.

As one of the big selling points of copy/swap is reduced coding, it can be ironic that using it can actually require more coding than letting the compiler default the special members.

Of course if the defaults do not do the right thing, then don't use them.  I'm simply saying that the defaults should be your first choice, ahead of copy/swap.

Comment: "Again I've explicitly defaulted the copy constructor. This corrects a bug in your version which neglects to copy Base." - Does that mean the default copy ctor calls the copy ctor of its base class?

Comment: @gartenriese:  That is correct.  All defaulted special members will iterate first over the bases, and then over the non-static data members, performing the indicated operation on each in turn.  Oh, except the destructor performs this iteration in the reverse order of the constructors.

Comment: Alright, thanks! BTW, I can't use the defaults because I have to copy some OpenGL stuff.

Comment: "The Derived move constructor does not need to move or copy anything from other since it is going to swap with other", - doesn't swap actually move things? Or did you mean "through a direct call"?

Comment: A why do you need to implement swap if you use default versions of copy and move constructors?

Comment: I meant through a direct call.

Comment: I wanted to include the complete public API of the OP's example which includes a swap.

Comment: clang-tidy does not recognize the `Derived& operator=(Derived other)` You have to implement both move and copy = operators instead.

Answer (score 4):

You implement `op=` exactly the same way for `Derived` as for `Base`:

```
Derived& operator=(Derived other) { swap(*this, other); return *this; }
```

I hope you are aware of the up- and down-sides of passing the argument by value there, though:

- Up-side: Only one function needed for all value categories.
- Down-Side: Second move for xvalues, move in addition to the needed copy for prvalues.

Other points to consider:

- Rule-of-thumb: Single-argument non-copy/move ctors should be `explicit`: You really don't want to have an implicit conversion from `int` to `Base`...
- You forgot to re-implement `swap` for `Derived` (swap all sub-objects, both base and member). You might forego it if `Derived` does not add any members though.

Comment: @Jon: But I like to thump with my thumb ;-) (Thanks.)

Comment: haha! C++ does have several rules of thumb that one should get thumped for not following! :-)

Comment: So you don't call any ctor of Base at all and do all the necessary things in Derived?

Comment: @gartenriese: Yes, at least not directly. (All Derived-ctors call a Base-ctor, and Derived::swap needs to call Base::swap)

Comment: But if I call Base::swap from Derived::swap, don't I swap Base twice when calling the move ctor of Derived? The first time in the move ctor of Base and the second time in the move ctor of Derived.

Comment: You need to swap each sub-object of the `Derived`, and at the moment you don't, you are only swapping the member- and not the base-subobject. `swap` is a normal function not a ctor or dtor, which magically will call the base-versions too.

Comment: But you said I'll have to call Base::swap inside Derived::swap. So when I call the move ctor of Derived it will first call the move ctor of Base which will call Base::swap. When the move ctor of Base is done, it goes inside the move ctor of Derived which will call Derived::swap. Which, also, will call Base::swap. Thus Base::swap will be called twice? Am I wrong?

Comment: Ah, your derived move-ctor is simply wrong: It needs to cheaply default-init the object and then swap everything. (If the default-ctor or swap is not cheap, it needs to be custom-coded). Which leads me to a question: Why don't you have a default-ctor? (Maybe add a default to ctor(int))

Comment: Ah, thanks, fixed my code in the question. EDIT: I did not think I would need a default ctor. Do I?

Comment: That's for you to decide. For copy&swap idiom applied to move-ctor, so cheap-init and swap, you just need a way to cheaply init a zombie-object.