# Copy constructor and assignment operators with polymorphism

Tags: c++, memory, constructor, polymorphism

Just failed an interview because of this, and I'm still confused:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int a) : a_(a) {}
    
    // Copy constructor
    
    // Assignment operator
    
private:
    int a_;
};
 
class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int a, int b) : A(a), b_(b) {
    }
    
    // Copy constructor
    
    // Assignment operator
    
private:
    int b_;
};
```

How do you implement the copy constr/assignment op, and why does the constructor of B have to have an A initialized in the initializer list? It doesn't work if it's not in the list.

Comment: It appears you could use a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116).

Comment: Here's how to do copy constructor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1021639/4641116

Comment: @M.A I fail to see the relevance, an initialiser list would be required even if everything in `A` was public.

Comment: @john you could have a setter inside the constructor body.

Comment: @M.A No you couldn't, base classes must be constructed before the body of the parent class constructor is entered, in other words you must use an initialiser list.

Comment: @john ah yes, the default constructor is not generated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do you implement the copy constr/assignment op

Trick question, I think. In this case the best option is to do absolutely nothing. Neither class contains (and [owns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024982/what-is-ownership-of-resources-or-pointers)) any resources requiring more than the default special member functions. Observe the [Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero).

Some style guides recommend explicitly defaulting special member functions. In this case

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    A(int a) : a_(a) {}
    
    A(const A &) = default;
    A& operator=(const A &) = default;
    
private:
    int a_;
};
```

may be appropriate.

> why does the constructor of B have to have an A initialized in the initializer list?

All class members and base classes must be fully constructed before entering the body of a constructor.

```cpp
B(int a, int b) 
{ // Entering constructor's body. A must be constructed before we get here.
}
```

`A` has no default constructor, so the constructor it does have must be explicitly called in the initializer list to construct the base class before the construction of `B` can proceed.

Addressing comment

`A`'s copy constructor and assignment operator are trivial:

```cpp
A(const A & src): a_(src.a_)
{

}

A& operator=(const A & src)
{
    a_ = src.a_;
    return *this;
}
```

`B` is a bit trickier because it also has to make sure `A` is copied

```cpp
B(const B & src): A(src), // copy the base class
                  b_(src.b_)
{

}

B& operator=(const B & src)
{
    A::operator=(src); // assign the base class by explicitly calling its 
                       // assignment operator
    b_ = src.b_;
    return *this;
}
```

Note: If I were hiring, I'd take the programmer who called me out on the trick question over the programmer who did the extra work and risked an unforced error.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But say you had to write out the copy constr/assignemnt op just for the sake of practice. Would it be the same as default for both of them? How would it work for B?

Comment: @LarryJing Updated answer.

Comment: [Here is a link to a more complicated case where the Copy and Swap Idiom is employed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973103/copy-swap-in-base-and-derived-class)

Answer (score 2):

> why does the constructor of B have to have an A initialized in the
> initializer list?

`A` only has one constructor which takes an int. `B` has `A` as a base class, which means that every `B` object must first construct an `A` object. How else are you going to construct that `A` object with it's required parameter except by using an initialiser list?